# Pass or append the value from input text to <a href="sms?:body=">

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to look for a how I can pass the value from in input textbox *href="sms:?body" It is a dynamic value that changes every time a user creates a new account. The idea is that once I click on the "Send Invite by SMS" the value or referral code that is included in the input text will also be included in the SMS body message.

[image]

Sample work in progress

```
<input class="input" disabled="true" placeholder="Referral Code" ng-model="account.referral_code_string" id="input-refcode">

<a ng-model="account.referral_code_string" href="sms:?body=" class="sms-btn" >Send Invite by SMS</a>
```

**Update**

I have managed to bind the input text on the sms anchor but when I try tap on the button the SMS app doesn't open up. It shows unsafe:sms but when I try using only href with a sample text(href="sms:?body=text") it opens up the SMS app

[image]

Comment: So you want to append the input value to the href value: sms:?body=referral code ?

Comment: Please add some more code and ask the question clearly or create a plunkr.

Comment: Basically the value inside the text box will pass on to the sms body message

Answer (score 1):

You can use ngHref to append it to your link.

`<a ng-href="sms?:body={{account.referral_code_string}}" class="sms-btn">Send Invite by SMS</a>`

See: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref

Working Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/3z145H?p=preview

Comment: Hello stephen, thank you for the hint. I managed to bind the value on the input box on to the anchor tag but I can't seem to open the sms whenever I tap on the anchor element using ng-href. If I use href only it seems to open the SMS app